# Winform bind dropdown from dictionary change name to a friendly name

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, combobox

Using .net 4.0 I have a win form combobox where I am binding from a dictionary, this is working fine.  However, I would like to change the name of what the user sees in the dropdown.

For example.. I would like the dropdown to say 10%, 20%, 30% ... 100%.

Here is my class that has the percentages and respective height values.

```
    enum SizeType : int
    {
        Height_10_Pct = 40,
        Height_20_Pct = 80,
        Height_30_Pct = 120,
        Height_40_Pct = 160,
        Height_50_Pct = 200,
        Height_60_Pct = 240,
        Height_70_Pct = 280,
        Height_80_Pct = 320,
        Height_90_Pct = 360,
        Height_100_Pct = 400)
    }
```

Creating the dictionary item

```
    public static Dictionary<string, int> ThumbSizeOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>(BuildThumbSizeOptions());

    public static Dictionary<string, int> BuildThumbSizeOptions()
    {
        ThumbSizeOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>();    
        foreach (SizeType val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SizeType)))
        {
            ThumbSizeOptions.Add(val.ToString(), (int)((val)));
        }
        return ThumbSizeOptions;
    }
```

Code to bind in the combo box in the Win Form:

```
     ddlThumbSize.DataSource = new BindingSource(ThumbSizePref.ThumbSizeOptions, null);
     ddlThumbSize.DisplayMember = "Key";
     ddlThumbSize.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use `switch/case` to rebind the enumerated constant to the new value you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [ListControl.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event: (`ComboBox` is a `ListControl`)

```
ddlThumbSize.Format += (s, e) => {
   e.Value += " %";
};
```

Comment: I ended up using:     e.Value = (e.Value.ToString()).Replace("Height_", "").Replace("_Pct", " %");

Answer (score 1):

1. In your particular case you can simply use `String.Format("{0}%", ((int)val) >> 2)` as a key in the `Dictionary`:

   ```
   ThumbSizeOptions.Add(String.Format("{0}%", ((int)val) >> 2), (int)val);
   ```
2. More general way is to use a custom attribute. Code for you:

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method)]
   public sealed class EnumDisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
   {
       public readonly string Displayname;

       public EnumDisplayNameAttribute(string displayname)
       {
           Displayname = displayname;
       }

       public static EnumDisplayNameAttribute Get<T>(T item)
       {
           FieldInfo member = typeof(T).GetField(item.ToString());
           if (member == null)
               return null;

           object[] attrs = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute), true);
           return attrs.Length == 0 ? null : attrs[0] as EnumDisplayNameAttribute;
       }
   }

   enum SizeType : int
   {
       [EnumDisplayName("10%")]
       Height_10_Pct = 40,
       [EnumDisplayName("20%")]
       Height_20_Pct = 80,
       [EnumDisplayName("30%")]
       Height_30_Pct = 120,
       [EnumDisplayName("40%")]
       Height_40_Pct = 160,
       [EnumDisplayName("50%")]
       Height_50_Pct = 200,
       [EnumDisplayName("60%")]
       Height_60_Pct = 240,
       [EnumDisplayName("70%")]
       Height_70_Pct = 280,
       [EnumDisplayName("80%")]
       Height_80_Pct = 320,
       [EnumDisplayName("90%")]
       Height_90_Pct = 360,
       [EnumDisplayName("100%")]
       Height_100_Pct = 400
   }

   public static Dictionary<string, int> ThumbSizeOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>(BuildThumbSizeOptions());

   public static Dictionary<string, int> BuildThumbSizeOptions()
   {
       ThumbSizeOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>();
       foreach (SizeType val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SizeType)))
       {
           ThumbSizeOptions.Add(EnumDisplayNameAttribute.Get(val).Displayname, (int)val);
       }
       return ThumbSizeOptions;
   }
   ```

Comment: I just read up on Attributes recently... Great solution as well.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `BuildThumbSizeOptions()` you can calculate your comboxbox values like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> BuildThumbSizeOptions()
{
    ThumbSizeOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    var max = (double)SizeType.Height_100_Pct;
    foreach (int val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SizeType)))
    {
        double perc = 100.0 / max * (double)val;
        ThumbSizeOptions.Add(perc + "%", val);
    }
    return ThumbSizeOptions;
}
```

The way you do it now has no dynamic.

Extending this function you can throw away your static enum `SizeType` and use only one variable which holds the maximum (100%) height.

```
public static double MAXIMUM_HEIGHT = 400.0;
public static Dictionary<string, int> BuildThumbSizeOptions()
{
    ThumbSizeOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    for (int perc = 10; perc <= 100; perc += 10)
    {
        var size = MAXIMUM_HEIGHT / 100.0 * perc;
        ThumbSizeOptions.Add(perc + "%", (int)size);
    }
    return ThumbSizeOptions;
}
```

Hope it helps although there are other answers ;-)